# Unzipping a .gz file using C#

Tags: c#

I have a tarred gunzip file called ZippedXmls.tar.gz which has 2 xmls inside it.
I need to programmatically unzip this file and the output should be 2 xmls copied in a folder.

How do I achieve this using C#?

Comment: How do you store two 2 "xmls" in one .gz file? Or is it actually a .tar.gz file?

Comment: Be aware that the gzip standard compresses and uncompresses byte streams only - if you have groups of files compressed, they are likely archived as a single file before being gzipped, as dtb has alluded.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I've used .Net's built-in [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) for gzipping byte streams and it works just fine.  I suspect that your files are tarred first, before being gzipped.

You've asked for code, so here's a sample, assuming you have a single file that is zipped:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("output.xml", FileMode.Create); // this is the output
GZipStream uncompressed = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress);

uncompressed.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length); // write all compressed bytes
uncompressed.Flush();
uncompressed.Close();

stream.Dispose();
```

**Edit:**

You've changed your question so that the file is a tar.gz file - technically my answer is not applicable to your situation, but I'll leave it here for folks who want to handle .gz files.

Comment: yes, the file is tarred and then zipped.how do i retrieve 2 xmls in this case then?Thanks for your help.

Comment: sharpziplib is what you want to use, then.  It handles tar.gz files.

Comment: Actually this code dies in my machine, complaining writing into the compressionstream is not supported....

Comment: @Lorgarn Not all stream operations are supported. What sort of stream is it that you're wrapping?

Comment: @CharlieSalts I am using the same steams as in the example. I used a FileByteReader to read the compressed source file into a byte array (which would be 'bytes' in the example above). Writing the bytearray in the GZipStream causes the exception. I solved this, by using 2 FileReaders for source and destination file and using the copy function of the GZipStream.

Comment: The linked MS documentation has a perfect example

Comment: How to initialize the bytes variable used in the code uncompressed.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length)?

Comment: byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];

Answer (score 7):

[sharpziplib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) should be able to do this

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is ancient, but search engines redirect here for how to extract gzip in C#, so I thought I'd provide a slightly more recent example:

```
using (var inputFileStream = new FileStream("c:\\myfile.xml.gz", FileMode.Open))
using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(inputFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
using (var outputFileStream = new FileStream("c:\\myfile.xml", FileMode.Create))
{
    await gzipStream.CopyToAsync(outputFileStream);
}
```

For what should be the simpler question of how to untar see: [Decompress tar files using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863875/decompress-tar-files-using-c-sharp)

Comment: I only get 5kb output file for some reason. But I have something else that works for me, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip;

// Specify the path to the input and output files
string inputFile = "input.gz";
string outputFile = "output.txt";

// Open the input file for reading
using (FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open))
{
    // Create a GZipInputStream to decompress the input file
    using (GZipInputStream gzipStream = new GZipInputStream(inputStream))
    {
        // Open the output file for writing
        using (FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create))
        {
            // Copy the decompressed data from the GZipInputStream to the output file
            gzipStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
        }
    }
}
```