# Sharpcompress: keywords don't exist in context

Tags: c#, tar, sharpcompress

I am trying to extract a .tgz file from my C# project, and I tried following the answers to this question:

[Decompress tar files using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863875/decompress-tar-files-using-c-sharp)

However, this code example does not work for me:

```
using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(tarPath))
{
    var reader = ReaderFactory.Open(stream);
    while (reader.MoveToNextEntry())
    {
        if (!reader.Entry.IsDirectory)
        {
            reader.WriteEntryToDirectory(extractPath, ExtractOptions.ExtractFullPath | ExtractOptions.Overwrite);
        }
    }
}
```

I get two errors:

1) ExtractOptions "does not exist in the current context". I am successfully using System.IO and SharpCompress.Readers, but I fail to find where ExtractOptions is located.

2) File "is a method, which is not valid in the given context". I have no idea why this happens!

In case it helps, I can successfully extract .zip files from the same path with a simple:

```
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

If there is a better way to extract the .tgz file that would also help!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a good night I was finally able to make it work.

#### Problem 1, "ExtractOptions does not exist".

As you can see [here](https://github.com/cwensley/sharpcompress/blob/master/SharpCompress/Common/ExtractOptions.cs), ExtractOptions is actually an enum, which needs to be initialized. This is not shown in the example I was using (perhaps it worked differently in an earlier version? Maybe the naming convention used in the example was throwing me off?)

#### Problem 2, "File is not valid in the given context"

Actually I had not given enough information to answer this one! The problem is that Visual Studio was taking for granted I was trying to use Controller.File instead of System.IO.File (but complained about the first not being valid in the context, instead of about a possible conflict). Controller.File is used in the web application framework ASP.NET MVC (which is what I am working on) to create FileContentResult objects.

#### Fixed code

(using System.IO; using SharpCompress.Readers;)

```
using (Stream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(tarPath))
{
    var reader = ReaderFactory.Open(stream);
    while (reader.MoveToNextEntry())
    {
        if (!reader.Entry.IsDirectory)
        {
           reader.WriteEntryToDirectory(extractPath, new ExtractionOptions() { ExtractFullPath = true, Overwrite = true });
        }
    }
}
```