# How to decompress a ZIP file in Windows 8 Metro without ZipArchive (zlib.net)

Tags: c#, zip, windows-8

I have a Windows 8 Metro application written in C#. I need to open a ZIP file and read the XML files that it contains. I used ZipArchive class but it became buggy in the current build and no longer works. Is there another way?

I tried googling for other ZIP libraries but the only one I could get to work in WinRT was zlib.net and this library does not have very frienly interface. How do you read XML files as string from ZIP using zlib.net in C#?

Comment: How did ZipArchive 'become buggy', can it be reproduced, have you filed a bug report, can you use an older version?

Comment: I filed a report and I am waiting for a workaround. But meanwhile I am trying to explore other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the built in library class [GZipStream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1348305/759558) or Deflate.

The docs say [system.io.compressions.Deflate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) supports zip (RFC 1951).

Comment: The GZipStream will not open a zip file GZip and a zip file is not the same thing..