# Unzip the .GZ file in worker Process of Azure

Tags: windows, azure

Can any1 provide me an Idea, How to implement unzipping  of .gz format file through Worker. If i try to write unzipping of file then, where i need to store unzipped file(i.e one text file
) , Will it be loaded in any location in azure. how can i specify the path in Windows Azure Worker process like current execting directory. If this approach doesnot work, then i need to create one more blob to store unzipped .gz file i.e txt.

-mahens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Worker Role, it is up to you how a .gz file arrive (downloaded from Azure Blob storage) however on the file is available you can use [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) to compress/uncompress a .GZ file. You can also find code sample in above link with Compress and Decompress function.

This SO discussion shares a few tools and code to explain how you can unzip .GZ using C#: 
[Unzipping a .gz file using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348198/unzipping-a-gz-file-using-c-sharp)

Next when you will use Decompress/Compress code in a Worker Role you have ability to store it directly to local storage (as suggested by JcFx) or use MemoryStream to store directly to Azure Blob Storage.

The following SO article shows how you can use  GZipStream to store unzipped content into MemoryStream and then use UploadFromStream() API to store directly to Azure Blob storage: 
[How do I use GZipStream with System.IO.MemoryStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722192/how-do-i-use-gzipstream-with-system-io-memorystream)

If you don't have any action related to your unzipped file then storing directly to Azure Blob storage is best however if you have to do something with unzipped content you can save locally as well as storage to Azure Blob storage back for further usage.

Answer (score 2):

This example, using SharpZipLib, extracts a .gzip file to a stream. From there, you could write it to [Azure local storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758708.aspx), or to blob storage:

http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/GZip-and-Tar-Samples.ashx