# Cannot extract the contents of a TGZ file using F# and SharpZipLib

Tags: f#, compression, sharpziplib

I am learning F# and Deedle.  I am trying to extract the contents of this [TGZ File](https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/dragontail-12.4.1.tgz) using SharpZipLib.  I downloaded the TGZ to my local drive.  I think I am close because out1 works, but out2 errs.  I am sure the code could be written better with pipe forwarding or composition, but it first needs to work.  Does anyone have any ideas?

```
open ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip
open  ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Tar

let extract path filename =
    let fullpath = Path.Combine(path, filename)
    let inSt = File.OpenRead(fullpath)
    let gSt = new GZipInputStream(inSt)
    let tar = TarArchive.CreateOutputTarArchive(gSt)
    let out1 = tar.ListContents
    let out2 = tar.ExtractContents(path)
    out2
    
extract "C:/Downloads/" "dragontail-12.4.1.tgz"
```

This is the error:

```
Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Tar.TarArchive.ExtractContents(String destinationDirectory, Boolean allowParentTraversal) in /_/src/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib/Tar/TarArchive.cs:line 620
   at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Tar.TarArchive.ExtractContents(String destinationDirectory) in /_/src/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib/Tar/TarArchive.cs:line 600
   at FSI_0104.extract(String path, String filename)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0104>.$FSI_0104.main@()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a SharpZipLib expert, but this works for me:

```ml
use tar = TarArchive.CreateInputTarArchive(gSt, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
tar.ExtractContents(path, true)
```

I think you have to explicitly allow for path traversal to unzip into an absolute path. See SharpZipLib unit tests in [this file](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/blob/master/test/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Tests/Tar/TarArchiveTests.cs).

Comment: 'System.Text.Encoding.UTF8' is the piece that made the difference.  I have no idea how I would have known to use that, but thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52200001/1594263

Looks like you should be using CreateInputTarArchive(). I modified your example to use CreateInputTarArchive(), and it worked for me.

BTW you're just assigning a function to out1, you're not actually calling ListContents().

Comment: Out1 and Out2 were just an easy switch for testing.  Out1 worked, but Out2 did not.