# Reading byte Array

Tags: c#, webservice-client

How can I read and convert to text file this byte[] value?

[image: screen from Debugger]

It is described in documentation like DataType="base64Binary" but I cant convert it to human readable format...

I have tried:

```
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(gadsContent.Value)
```

and got

```
?\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\0?ZY??Zr~?W5vp??\0?t??6@\b\t???pL\bm\b???8?????/^~????L?/Q@Q??????...
```

```
Convert.ToBase64String(gadsContent.Value)
```

and got

```
H4sIAAAAAAAAANVaWZPiWnJ+51cQNRETdnCrtAAC9XT1jDZACAm0guRwTAhtCLSAFrQ4/OCxw3/AL15+hp8c9ttM/y8fUUBR273d99qecEd3FTonM09uJzM/0Z9/W4...
```

Update:

Now I read that this has compression GZIP...
How can I decompress and decode it ?

Comment: I think you are asking your question at too low of a level. Perhaps start with your web service calling code and even identify and provide information about the web service.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `System.Text.Encoding` class to convert between string and byte array. Based on the encoding of your input string/byte array, use the appropriate property from this class.

Here is a sample for **UTF8** encoding.

```
var someString = "Some text input";

//Convert the string to byte array
var byteArray= System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(someString);

//Convert a byte array to string
var stringFromByteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
```

You have many other encoding options in this class. Use the one as needed

- UTF32
- UTF8
- Unicode
- ASCII  ( *Ascii is like really old*)

Comment: I have tried decoding in many method but something is wrong. String is unreadable for me ... like in Chinese language :)

Answer (score 1):

If a file contains a base64-encoded binary array, you need to follow these steps:

1. Open the file *as text*, using appropriate text encoding (ASCII, UTF8, etc). You can ask .NET to try to detect the encoding if you want.
2. Read the text into a string.
3. Convert the string into a byte array using [`Convert.FromBase64String()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx).

The shortest possible example I could come up with looks like this:

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.UTF8);
byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
```

If you don't know the encoding, you can omit the argument and hope .NET can detect it:

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

> (these are not text bytes, this does not apply: Assuming those are text bytes, you need a text decoder: try
>
> System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(x.Value)
>
> )

Seeing as the first two bytes are 31, 139 that should mean it's GZip bytes.

Stack Overflow has an article on decoding Gzip:

[Unzipping a .gz file using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348198/unzipping-a-gz-file-using-c-sharp)

At this point I can't tell if it's a .tar.gz file (tarred first, then gzipped). You'll have to un-gzip it to see what you get and then we can look at that.

Comment: I have tried everything method but something is wrong. String is unreadable... Like in Chinese language :)